# How is to define the exact time when the file was created and/or modified?

Tags: files, timestamps, nautilus

I have tried to configure Nautilus, Dolphin, Krusader, mc. None of them shows the seconds. Didn’t find such option in properties.

Comment: You cannot configure `nautilus` to show the seconds (not the more recent versions at least) - you'll have to either patch the source code or write a `nautilus` extension (in _C_ or _Python_). I don't  know about the other file managers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `stat`.

```
stat testfile
  File: ‘testfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 9770        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-02-24 18:01:15.491879291 +0100
Modify: 2017-02-24 18:01:15.491879291 +0100
Change: 2017-02-24 18:01:15.491879291 +0100
 Birth: -
```